# Matrix product (notation in answer)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose I have a matrix $C=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and a vector $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

I want to write the matrix product $C\mathbf{x}$, should the answer be vector notation (bold) or not?

I mean vector notation
$$\mathbf{y}= C\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}=x_1
$$
or scalar notation
$$
y= C\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}=x_1
$$
I use upright letters for matrices, bold letters for vectors. Non-bold for scalars.

Answer (score 0):

$$C\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}=[x_1]$$
(note the brackets around $x_{1}$) is a

- $1 \times 1$ matrix, or
- a row vector of length one, or
- a column vector of length one,

you choose.

Comment: Thanks! But using scalar notation $y$ (not bold) is wrong?

Comment: The only reason to choose a particular notation is to please your instructor ;-)